# OpenShift/Kubernetes: RWX volume successfully attached, but mounting fails randomly

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, storage

I have an issue that I thought was related to storage but it's not so clear anymore...

On OpenShift (4.3.25), I have pods configured with volumeMounts using RWX volumes (CephFS from rook-ceph). But randomly (although easily reproducible) the mount fails whereas the volume attach succeeds. It happens in different projects, for different container images.

Here are the details on what happens:

- During container creation:

```
Successfully assigned staging/test-ztph6 to ip-10-0-134-186.ca-central-1.compute.internal
```

then

```
AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-1b42e048-db99-4db1-858d-b208585f4c3c"
```

So it appeared that the volume was attached.

- But then:

```
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[hmf-data-restricted-raw-ccso], unattached volumes=[hmf-data-public hmf-data-restricted-raw-ccso hmf-data-restricted-processed-ccso hmf-data-restricted-raw-moh hmf-data-restricted-processed-moh default-token-vhnwz hmf-data-confidential]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

- So I checked this particular volume that would not mount:

```
hmf-data-restricted-raw-ccso
PVC hmf-data-restricted-raw-ccso => PV pvc-1b42e048-db99-4db1-858d-b208585f4c3c
```

- I connected directly as root to the host where the container was scheduled, then:

```
sh-4.4# mount | grep pvc-1b42
172.30.151.123:6789,172.30.109.18:6789,172.30.154.247:6789:/volumes/csi/csi-vol-cba856b8-bd42-11ea-91b6-0a580a800279/ad6e4442-5415-4837-bcce-8c8c232b93fb on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pvc-1b42e048-db99-4db1-858d-b208585f4c3c/globalmount type ceph (rw,relatime,name=csi-cephfs-node,secret=<hidden>,acl,mds_namespace=myfs)
```

So it appeared that the volume was indeed mounted.

- Let's check this:

```
sh-4.4# cd /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/pv/pvc-1b42e048-db99-4db1-858d-b208585f4c3c/globalmount

sh-4.4# ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  4 root       root  2 Jul  3 16:13 .
drwxr-x---. 3 root       root 46 Jul  8 14:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 1002590000 root  0 Jul  3 16:13 .ipynb_checkpoints
drwxr-xr-x  2 1002590000 root  6 Jul  3 16:13 ccis
```

Which is the content of the volume that I tried to mount in the container.

So apparently there is no issue with the storage, at least that I can identify. The volume is attached and mounted on the host, it just won't mount in the container.
Any idea where I should look next?

Comment: Have you compared the pod spec for the ones it is working with the ones it is not working?

Comment: Oh, I was not clear enough on that. The same container image, with the same spec, sometimes works, sometimes hangs. To reproduce/test, I've set this up as a Job that I can launch and relaunch again, so it's always the same thing. It's not even predictable, like "after 10 consecutive success there is a huge change it will fail". It can fail on the first try, the last, anything in between. I also can launch Jobs in parallel, again with the same image/specs. Some will succeed, some will fail. Does not also depend on the node it runs on. It can succeed or fail on any worker node...